# How to deploy Angular App with GitLab CI/CD

Tags: linux, gitlab, cicd

I've been trying to setup a CI/CD Pipeline on my Repo which runs common tasks like linting/tests etc. I've successfully setup a Gitlab-Runner which is working fine. The only part I'm stuck is the "deploy" part.

**When I run my build, how do I actually get the files into my `/var/www/xyz` folder.**

I get that everything is running in a Docker Container and I can't just *magically* copy paste my files there, but i don't get how I get the files on my **actual** server-directory. I've been searching for days for good docs / explanations, so as always, StackOverflow is my last resort for help.

I'm running on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VPS and a SaaS GitLab-Repository if that info is needed. That's my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: timbru31/node-alpine-git

before_script:
  - git fetch origin

stages:
  - setup
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

#All Setup Jobs
Install Dependencies:
  stage: setup
  interruptible: true
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm i -g @nrwl/cli
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/

# All Test Jobs
Lint:
  stage: test
  script: npx nx run nx-fun:lint

Tests:
  stage: test
  script: npx nx run nx-fun:test

Deploy:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ls /var/www/
    - npx nx build --prod --output-path=dist/
    - cp -r dist/* /var/www/html/neostax/
  only:
    refs:
      - master
```

Normally I would ssh into my server, run the build, and then copy the build to the corresponding web-directory.

**TL;DR - How do I get files from a GitLab-Runner to an actual directory on the server?**

Comment: Can you update your question with the contents of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? Also, how would you deploy without CI/CD? Ie, how would you manually do it? Do you for example scp a tar file to a remote host, ssh into the host, extract the archive, and move the files somewhere?

Comment: @AdamMarshall Done, hopefully this info helps!